# How to get correct extension method for a generic class method?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, extension-methods

I came across this recently while writing the code. Is there a way we can write a code in base class so it identifies the correct extension method based on the type?

```
namespace GenericsInheritance
{
    public class Animal { }

    public class Dinasaur : Animal { }

    public class Dragon : Animal { }

    public abstract class Zoo<T> where T : Animal
    {
        public virtual string IdentifyYourSelf(T record)
        {
            //Calling extension method
            string name = record.IdentifyYourSelf();
            return name;
        }
    }

    public class DinasaurZoo : Zoo<Dinasaur> 
    {
        //I could use this, just wanted to try if base class method does identify the correct extension method for the type.
        //public override string IdentifyYourSelf(Dinasaur record)
        //{
        //    return record.IdentifyYourSelf();
        //}
    }

    public class DragonZoo : Zoo<Dragon> { }

    public class AnimalZoo : Zoo<Animal> { }

    //Extensions methods class.
    public static class LieDetector
    {
        public static string IdentifyYourSelf(this Animal record) { return "Animal"; }

        public static string IdentifyYourSelf(this Dinasaur record) { return "Dinasaur"; }

        public static string IdentifyYourSelf(this Dragon dog) { return "Dragon"; }

        //It works if I use this.
        //public static string IdentifyYourSelf<T>(this T record) where T : Animal
        //{            
        //    if (record is Dinasaur) { var dinasaur = record as Dinasaur; return IdentifyYourSelf(dinasaur); }
        //    else if (record is Dragon) { var dragon = record as Dragon; return IdentifyYourSelf(dragon); }        
        //    else return "I do not exist";
        //}
    }

    public class FbiInterrogation
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var animal = new Animal();
            var dinasaur = new Dinasaur();
            var dragon = new Dragon();
            var dinasaurZoo = new DinasaurZoo();
            var dragonZoo = new DragonZoo();
            var animalZoo = new AnimalZoo();

            string name = dinasaurZoo.IdentifyYourSelf(dinasaur); //Prints Animal expecting Dinasaur
            name = dragonZoo.IdentifyYourSelf(dragon); //Prints Animal expecting Dragon
            name = animalZoo.IdentifyYourSelf(animal); //Prints Animal

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Extension methods are resolved according to the static type of the variable on which they're called, not the run-time type.  So the answer to your question is "no" -- you have to do it via an overload in the derived class.

Comment: overload or override?

Comment: @phoog: put this into an answer, because it *is* the answer. It is override, not overload, by the way.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger thanks for the correction and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods are resolved according to the static type of the variable on which they're called, not the run-time type. So the answer to your question is "no" -- you have to do it via an override in the derived class, or by cumbersome type checking, as you indicate in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This could actually be achieved using reflection, though I'm not sure if it's the best idea to do so:

```
public abstract class Zoo<T> where T : Animal
{
    public virtual string IdentifyYourSelf(T record)
    {
        return typeof(LieDetector).GetMethod("IdentifyYourSelf", new[] {typeof(T)}, null).Invoke(record, new object[] {record}) as string;
    }
}
```